# Google Analytics Simple visitors count

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to GA and I have the following scenario:
I have a website that does not require the GA services at all except for one page.
This page's URL something like this: http://example.com/events?eventId=1234

What I try to achieve is to count the visitors for the different events specified in the parameter. (So later I can retrieve this information and I can show how many people visited a particular event's site).

I have been looking at https://www.google.com/analytics for a while however I could not figure out how to make the GA distinguish by the parameters. So far I registered at GA and I have the unique code and I can include this to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Additionally this web application is implemented with Play framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) or just log a [virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews)

e.g.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/events/{id}']);
```

Replace the `{id}` with the actual `id`

Comment: You can use whatever parameters as part of your url, e.g.  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/events?eventId={id}&eventName={name}']);, since they are just virtual.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the on-page GA code snippet will record the URL, minus protocol and domain.  That means if you have

`www.example.com/events?eventId=1234`

vs.

`www.example.com/events?eventId=4567`

You will see 2 separate entries in your pages reports:

```
/events?eventId=1234
/events?eventId=4567
```

So out-of-the-box you should be good to go.

However...one issue you brought up in a comment:

> does it work even if there are other parameters as well?

Yes it will, and that presents a problem.  Because these 2 will also count as 2 separate entries:

```
www.example.com/events?eventId=123&a=b
www.example.com/events?eventId=123&a=c
```

In order to get around this, you will need to as tszming mentioned in his answer: track with a custom event (or custom variable), or else override the default page name with something of your choice. Or you can do both; each method is basically a different way of looking at the same basic data, and allows you to do slightly different things.  But for answering your basic question of "how many people went to {eventId} version of the page, all of the options will answer that.

sidenote: in any case, all of these solutions involve getting a query string param. GA does not have a built in method for grabbing a query string parameter value, so you will have to grab that value yourself.  Unfortunately, javascript does not have a built in way of doing it either.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy to write a function that will do it for you (just google "javascript get query param").

Comment: All right. Now on the Google page I can see that I am looking at my page. The overall count shows 0. I guess it will be updated later. Thanks for the info guys. Now I'll try to work around with the issue Crayon mentioned however I don't know which solution would be a better approach and I need to read through GA API as well in order to show the results on my page.

Comment: GA officially states that it can take up to 24 hours for data to show up in all the reports.  Though in my experience, it usually only takes an hour or two for basic page view type data in the reports, longer for the "overview" pages